# ArcGIS 10.6 opening mxd from 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-10.6

I previously had 10.5 and opened up an ArcGIS 10.2 versions MXD.  This week, I upgraded to 10.6 and tried to open the MXD from that same 10.2.  That MXD would not open. All it would do is "not responding".  I copied, renamed it and even re-downloaded it from the email it was sent from.  Nothing.  Corrupted?

I opened up older mxd's of mine when I had 10.1.  Another Mapper used different versions 10.5 and 10.2, could not open that one either.  But, could open others.

Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 6):

It could be something in that particular MXD is corrupt. You could try two things.

The first is to run the "MXD Doctor" it normally comes with the installation of ArcMap. I am not sure if it comes with 10.6. Normally it is found in (using Window 7): Start -> Programs -> ArcGIS -> Desktop Tool -> MXD Doctor

I have had some success in using this tool to recover corrupted MXDs.

Another alternative method, would be to check the Data Sources of the MXD. It is possible that perhaps a layer in the MXD is creating the error. Open ArcCatalog and navigate to the MXD giving issues, Right Click and select "Set Data Sources". This opens a window with all of the data loaded in the MXD. Try checking each data source to ensure it is reading information from the correct locations.

I have had issues with some of my MXDs where I have used a base map. These MXDs often will not open and I either have to reset my PC or run through the steps above to try and avoid the crash on opening.

Comment: I forgot to add.. MXD Dr also went to NOT RESPONDING only with these mxd's.

I will try that in Catalog.

Comment: I tried doing that with Catalog this morning, same issue.. "Not responding" only to those mxd's that came from the same guy who created them in .  All other mxd's function like they should.

Comment: So the originator of the MXD cannot open the MXD? Is it linked to any online sources or external databases? I saw this link this morning and thought maybe it would work for you too? I think ignore the question, but look at the answers given to the issue. They may offer ideas for your problems.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84855/arcmap-10-2-crashing-when-opening-mxd-files?rq=1

Comment: The originator can, but myself and one other person using his ArcGIS program can not either.  

I ran the ArcGIS defragmenter, that did not help.

I tried the Catalog, right click for Data Source and was hoping I would be able to delete layers in there but I do not think that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION.. I ended up opening a blank mxd and clicked to the problem mxd. It opened 15-20-ish minutes later.  All the layers were broken from all the data being moved to a new drive.

Thank you for all the help as I learned a few new problem-solving ways.